# Rails integration test failing on Class.count - nil.nill.NIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

ENV=development

Im getting a weird error that makes no sense to me

when i run an integration test with Myclass.count I get error

> ERROR["test_micropost_interface", MicropostsInterfaceTest, 2016-01-20 23:50:17 +0000]
>    test_micropost_interface#MicropostsInterfaceTest (1453333817.28s)
>   ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

the code is and was working im sure !

```
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
     post microposts_path, micropost: { content: "" }
    end
```

I ran a console and Micropost.count returns 32

Is this possibly an issue with the fixtures not propagating ?
im stumped :( take advice on where to look !

Comment: The error suggests that the thing you are calling `.count` on incorrectly is in the view itself - your question suggests that you think it is `Micropost.count` in the test that is causing the error. Might be worth clarifying.

Comment: the "thing" Im calling count on is the Microposts class Its in the Microposts Integration Test and behaves properly from the same syntax in a console

Somehow the Micrposts class is comming up as a NilClass in the integration test and I was wondering if someoen else had experienced this or managed to resolve this ? Its most likey my mistake somewhere - but im not sure where to look

Comment: did you do rake:db:test:prepare?

Comment: Nope- i just looked up - rake:db:test:prepare 

I never new of its existance ! I shall attempt it imediatly

Comment: Ok Ive ran this it reports nothing and when i rake test its still throwing the error on count of Micropost as a Nilclass

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is coming from within one of your views rather than being a problem with the test itself.

It's probably worth removing the silencing on backtraces and seeing if you get a more detailed error which will hopefully point to the error more accurately.

In `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb` you can uncomment the last line to get rails to show the entirety of an error. I often change this line to:

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers! if Rails.env.test?
```

to get full backtraces when I'm running tests.

Comment: I did this it just throws back AN AWFUL LOT of information but without any reason as to wehere to look, the full backtrace dosnt assist, the issue is Micropost not being a class in the micropost integration test for some reason :(